# Taylor polynomial of $e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$ at $x=0$

Tags: taylor-expansion

How can I write the taylor polynomial of $e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$ at $x=0$?

When I use brute force I get $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(x^2)^k}{2^k k!}$

but when I do it by myself all the derivatives are zero.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: The derivatives will only be zero for a highest odd terms of the Taylor polynomial. I think you forgot to apply the product rule.

Comment: your function is even so all derivative of odd oder are zero

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let $f : x \mapsto e^{x^2/2}$.

First, $f(0)=1$ so the first coefficient is $a_0=1$.

Differentiate one time
$$
f'\left(x\right)=xe^{x^2/2} 
$$
that value $0$ when $x=0$ so $a_1=0$.
Again ; 
$$
f''\left(x\right)=\left(xe^{x^2/2} \right)'=e^{x^2/2}+x\left(xe^{x^2/2}\right)
$$
that equals $1$ when $x=0$ so the coefficient $a_2=1/2$ as expected.
You can keep doing it to find the first terms of the polynomial.

Comment: Can I use the expansion for $e^x$?

Comment: Absolutely you can ! You apply it for $x=x^2/2$.

Comment: Can you explain why is that correct? It's not the same function

Comment: The expansion of $x \mapsto e^x$ is true for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. and you can right that $e^{x^2/2}$  is $f \circ g$  with $f$ being exponential function and $g : x \mapsto x^2/2 \in \mathbb{R}$ so you just substitute $x$ by $x^2/2$ in which the expansion is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

The Taylor's expansion for $y\to0$ is

$$e^y=1+y+\frac{y^2}{2!}+...+\frac{y^k}{k!}+o(x^k)$$

then for $\frac{x^2}{2}\to 0$ we can simply replace and obtain

$$e^\frac{x^2}{2}=1+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{8}+...+\frac{x^{2k}}{2^k\cdot k!}+o(x^{2k})$$